# How can I locate unused drivers (kext files) on my mac which I see exist using kextstat command?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic, driver

I've been receiving crazy kernel panics for years, and I've resolved to get rid of them once and for all.

I was recommended to remove all the 3rd party drivers that appear in the reports as they could easily be the culprits for the panic - one of those was the remote controller app by iospirit. I reoved the app as recommended by the devs, but I still see the drivers in the report, even though they're not supposed to exist any more on my machine!

This is what I see using textstat for the iospirit leftovers which I have not been able to locate:

```
kextstat | grep iospirit
  103    0 0xffffff7f8100d000 0x2000     0x2000     com.iospirit.CandelairIRBaseDriver (1) C2DBE90A-C38C-3012-8CEB-DF98F742553F 
  164    1 0xffffff7f81010000 0x2c000    0x2c000    com.iospirit.driver.rbiokithelper (1.33) 6A3D7305-1A0D-38C4-A832-D84B69F0C492 
  178    0 0xffffff7f83886000 0x2000     0x2000     com.iospirit.driver.AppleIRController (4001) DAF6B9AF-DF84-3081-9426-3B4FEDD14D09
```

Any idea how I can find those iospirit driver guys?

Performing a simple search for iospirit on "This Mac" finds nothing :(

Thank you!

Comment: Im not sure but I think you can start up in Disk utility and then click verify??

Comment: What do you get, when you search for the bundle id? `kextfind -bundle-id -s com.iospirit.CandelairIRBaseDriver` Also System Information > Software > Extensions shows the path, if you can find them there.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for the bundle id with `kextfind`.

```
kextfind -case-insensitive -bundle-id -substring 'com.iospirit.' -print
```

The above should print a list of the kernel extensions (kexts) you've mentioned, including their paths.

Usually kexts are found in...
`/System/Library/Extensions/`
`/Library/Extensions/`
...or within `Application packages` and `/Library/Application Support/`.

There is also `StagedExtensions`, since the introduction of "User-Approved Kernel Extension Loading", where they can also be found in e.g.
`/Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/`

StackOverflow has a relevant question and answers about "StagedExtensions", including removal here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions

For more information on user-approved extension loading and their locations (mentioned above) see also this archived Tech Note from Apple about "[User-Approved Kernel Extension Loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html)"

Comment: Wow, finally found the little hooligan haha
Thanks Redarm, removed the kext and are very curious to see what happens next :)